# Compare string in php file and string from cli

Tags: php, fopen, fgets, command-line-interface, php-stream-wrappers

when I get input from cli, I var_dump it and this showed for me:

```
    string(2) "Y
"
```

So how I understand I receive the single char and the bag of blank spaces, so this code will return false `($input == "Y")`. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily remove all this whitespace using `trim()`

```
(trim($input) == 'Y')
```

Comment: thanks I solve it by reg exp preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $line)

Comment: that may work too, but it's a huge overkill if you want to just remove the spaces (and newline)